# Cannot launch software centre, neither update

Tags: apt

```
m@samsung:~$ sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
[sudo] password for m: 
rm: cannot remove `/var/lib/apt/lists/partial': Is a directory
m@samsung:~$ sudo apt-get update
N: Ignoring file 'gnomebaker.lis' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gnomebaker.list (URI parse)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
m@samsung:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you made some typos when adding the gnomebaker repo. Remove it and apt wil work again.

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gnomebaker*
```

Comment: thnx, but still not working

Comment: m@samsung:~$ sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gnomebaker*
[sudo] password for m: 
m@samsung:~$ sudo apt-get update
E: Type 'airjordan' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.

Comment: Looks like you have some more corruption on your hand there. What's in the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list file?

Comment: ehm, how can i find out ? :P

Comment: By opening it in a text editor...

Comment: unfortunately i cannot even locate it